# Most "full control" users can't access datasheet view or export to Excel

Tags: excel, datasheet

All but the administrator users with "full control" and/or "contribute" permissons on a certain list do not recieve the datasheet view option, and when they try to export to Excel there is a permissions related error. As I understand it, such users should have these options.

What might be causing this behaviour?

Comment: Unfortunatly, the unexpected behaviour is happening in Internet Explorer 8.

Answer (score 2):

Use Internet Explorer only as the browser. Is not working for other browsers.

Comment: I'd further refine that to use 32 bit Internet Explorer in case users are running 64 bit Windows OS.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.The users in question are using 32 bit IE on 32 bit Windows, however.

Comment: http://sal-sharepoint2010.blogspot.com.au/2010/05/full-control-user-cannot-edit-web-parts.html may be the source of the problem.